# No Mouse or Keyboard in X after NVIDIA Driver Update

Tags: nvidia, xorg, kde, xserver, gpu-driver

I accidentally updated my NVIDIA drivers with apt. After reinstalling the old version (410) I end up in a command line login. Here is everything fine and `nvidia-smi` says that driver and cuda are installed properly.
When I `startx` I get my desktop, but mouse and keyboard don't work. Means my keyboard works in tty but not in X.

Has anyone an idea, how I could get my desktop back?

OS: Kubuntu 18.04

GPU: NVIDIA RTX 2080 Ti

Comment: Paste the output of `xinput`, if it doesn't work try `DISPLAY=:0 xinput`.

Comment: Both say `Unable to connect to X server`.

Comment: Try to detect the correct `DISPLAY` variable: https://superuser.com/questions/647464/how-to-get-the-display-number-i-was-assigned-by-x

Comment: I don't get any output from that command. Is that even possible? Seems strange to me. But I'm going to double check it because I had to type it manually - maybe I made a mistake.

Comment: Nope, really no output...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install the Nvidia drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers)

Comment: @KristopherIves Okay, wich part of it do you mean exactly? `sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf` doesn't work because I don't have that file.
To be honest for now I would be happy to have a working desktop with the nouveau driver so that I can reinstall the NVIDIA drivers on top of the working system.

Comment: Have you tried installing the `Nvidia` drivers using CLI?

Comment: After a lot of research without solutions i came up with reinstalling my OS. Nevertheless thank you all for your help!